# ¿Qué diferencias hay entre hacer trigger("click") y click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

En una aplicación web, me he encontrado el siguiente código (simplificado):

```
$("#miInput").trigger("click");
$("#miInput").click();
```

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre esas dos líneas? ¿Es mejor usar una sobre la otra? (y por qué)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según el [código de jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js), `.click()` forma parte de los alias de eventos, los cuales llaman a `.on()` o `.trigger()` según si hay argumentos o no, respectivamente:

```
jQuery.each( ( "blur focus focusin focusout resize scroll click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup contextmenu" ).split( " " ),
    function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
} );
```

Dicho esto, la única diferencia (mínima) sería el pasar por una función menos usando `.trigger("click")`.

Comment: ¿El código que has puesto es el interno de jQuery o sólo una simulación de cómo funciona?

Comment: Es el interno de jQuery (lo puedes ver en el enlace "código de jQuery").

Comment: Gracias. No me había dado cuenta del enlace :$

Answer (score 2):

sacado de aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click

básicamente, si al "click" no se le pasan parámetros acaba haciendo una llamada a la función "trigger". Por esto mismo, trigger es más rápido.

Saludos,

Roger